# How to control the back address ident and remove the sender address in scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script, letters

I'd like to remove the box which holds the sender data and only have the backaddress. 
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the correct command is `\KOMAoptions{firsthead=false}`